# How to create dict with 2 keys and one value?

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

In python I can define dictionary as:

```
d = {}
```

and store data as:

```
d['a1'] = 1
```

How to store 2 keys?

```
d['a1']['b1'] = 1
d['a1']['b2'] = 2

d['a2']['b1'] = 3
d['a2']['b2'] = 4
```

and then print all keys and values for e.g. `d['a1']` which would be:

```
b1 -> 1
b2 -> 2
```

Comment: You're going to need a nested dictionaries—a dictionary-of-dictionaries—to do that.

Comment: And that's what the accepted answer does (as well as @LemonPi's) — `defaultdict` is a subclass (i.e. specialized) dictionary which in this case is being used to automatically create the sub-dictionaries whenever something is first assigned to one to one of its keys. Check out the [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) documentation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `defaultdict` from `collections` module ([docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict)

d['a1']['b1'] = 1
d['a1']['b2'] = 2

d['a2']['b1'] = 3
d['a2']['b2'] = 4

print(d['a1'])
```

Prints:

```
{'b1': 1, 'b2': 2}
```

Comment: I like this the most.. Cleanest and easy to understand!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` but you cannot mix an int and dict assignment to `d['a1']` as in your example.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict)

d['a1']['b1'] = 1
d['a1']['b2'] = 2

d['a2']['b1'] = 3
d['a2']['b2'] = 4
d['a3'] = 1

print(d['a1'])
print(d['a3'])

>>> {'b1': 1, 'b2': 2}
>>> 1
```

If you really want to first assign 1 to `d['a1']` then change it to a dictionary, you'll have to manually do that after the assignment with `d['a1'] = {}`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create nested dicts:

```
d = {'a1': {'b1': 1, 'b2': 2}, 'a2': {'b1': 3, 'b2': 4}}
```

And then just:

```
for k, v in d['a1'].items():
    print(k, v)
```

Answer (score -1):

That's not one `dict`; it's a `dict` that has other `dict`s as values.

```
d['a1'] = {'b1': 1}
d['a1'] = {'b2': 2}
d['a2'] = {'b1': 3}
d['a2'] = {'b2': 4}
```

From there, you can work with each of the nested `dict`s as you would any other value. For example

```
for k1, v1 in d.items():
    for k2, v2 in v1.items():
        print("{} -> {} -> {}".format(k1, k2, v2))
```